# i am using ui.router in angularjs i am not getting the desired output

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am providing the app.js code

```
'use strict';

var dpApp = angular.module('dpApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages','ui.router']);

dpApp.config(function ($mdThemingProvider, $routeProvider,$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
  var dpcolor = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('deep-purple', {
    '500': '#6A1B9B'
  });

  $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('dpcolor', dpcolor);

  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('dpcolor');

  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'appCtrl'
    })
    .state('register', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
      controller: 'appCtrl'
    })
    .state('forgot', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/forgot.html',
      controller: 'appCtrl'
    })
    .state('patient-profile', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/patient-profile.html',
      controller: 'appCtrl'
    })
    .state('edit-profile', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/edit-profile.html',
      controller: 'appCtrl'
    })
    .state('med-record', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/med-record.html',
      controller: 'appCtrl'
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("login");

});
```

The routing is happening but I am getting a blank page.It works  if I use `$routeProvider`

Comment: Is there any error you are getting in you browser console

Comment: Had you added the ui-view tag in HTML ??

Comment: If you are using ui.router module, then you have to specify <div ui-view></div> tag in index.html, same for ngRoute module, specify <div ng-view></div>. Please specify  <div ui-view></div> tag in root page(index.html) and please remove ngRoute dependency. Prefer to use only one routing module.

Comment: You have both ngRoute and ui.router injected. You should choose one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add url parameter of $stateProvider like

```
 .state('login', {
  url:'/login'
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'appCtrl'
})
```

and you don't need $routeProvider